# Rails - Correct location to place cron jobs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cron, jobs, software-quality

This question is more related to code quality and organization.

I am developing a Rails application, and we have some cron jobs that we execute daily. Those jogs are already working, but currently I am placing them inside my models, for example:

```
def update_boleto_orders_payment_status
    orders = Order.boleto_unpaid_orders
    orders.each do |o|
      order = HTTParty.get("https...",
                    headers: {"Authorization" => "Basic #
{encode_auth_token}"})
      order_status = JSON.parse(order.body).symbolize_keys![:status]
      o.update_column(:paid, true) if(order_status.eql? "AUTHORIZED")
    end
  end
```

I use this method to update my order status, and this method is located inside my Order model.

My question is: Assuming rails best practices and conventions, is it correct to place this jobs inside my model? Or should I place this kind of methods somewhere else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating a job class in the app/jobs directory is pretty common these days.

Comment: So everything related to jobs and scheduling I can put inside a new directory jobs, it sounds better than putting inside my models :)

Comment: Yes. Rails added a framework a few years ago called ActiveJob, but you can also just write plain ruby objects that respond to #perform. For example: UpdateBoletoOrderPaymentsStatusJob#perform